Trying to clarify the definition of an instanton
The definition of an instanton, in [this Wikipedia article], is: a
"classical solution to equations of motion with a finite, non-zero action" and further specifies that it is "on a Euclidean spacetime".
That seems to allow almost any classical solution (like exponential functions, standing waves, etc.) It fails to answer the obvious question:
When is a solution not an instanton?
As an example we can look at [Yang-Mills theory]. From the usual Lagrangian:
$$
\mathcal L_{\small \text{YM}} = -{\small \frac{_1}{^4}} F^a_{\mu\nu}F_a^{\mu\nu}, 
\quad \text{with} \quad
F^a_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu^a - \partial_\nu A_\mu^a + g f^{abc} A_\mu^b A_\nu^c,
$$
the Euler-Lagrange equations, ${\small \partial_\mu}\frac{{\large \delta} \mathcal L}{{\large \delta}\partial_\mu A_\nu^a}
= \frac{{\large \delta} \mathcal L}{{\large \delta} A_\nu^a}
$, will then give us the somewhat complicated, non-linear field equations
$
\partial_\mu F^{a\mu\nu} = g f^{abc} F^{b\nu\rho} A_\rho^c,
$
which contain linear, quadratic and cubic terms in $A_\mu^a$, after $F^a_{\mu\nu}$ is filled in.
Fortunately, above-mentioned instanton article also gives an ingenious way (Corrigan and Fairlie, see [examples in ${\mathbb R}^4$]) to solve this for the $SU(2)$ case:
$A_\mu^a = \sigma_{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial^\nu\rho}{\rho},$ with $\rho(x)$ any harmonic function, while the $\sigma_{\mu\nu}$ are certain combinations of the $SU(2)$ generators.
The article goes on to mention that the most basic harmonic function in ${\mathbb R}^4$ is $\frac1{|x|^2}$. If we use that, we would get a solution with nice scaling properties:
$$\begin{align}
A_\mu^a &= \sigma^a_{\mu\nu}\,|x|^2 \partial^\nu{\small \frac{1}{|{ x}|^2}}
 = -2\,\sigma^a_{\mu\nu}\,\partial^\nu \log|x|
\\[6pt] \Rightarrow
A_\mu^a(\lambda\, x) &={\small\frac1{\lambda}}A_\mu^a(x), 
\quad F_{\mu\nu}^a(\lambda\, x) ={\small\frac1{\lambda^2}}F_{\mu\nu}^a(x), 
\end{align}$$
but that also shows that the fields blow up at the origin. In fact, the function $\rho$ used here is not harmonic in this singular point.
If we allow this, we could also call the Coulomb potential in EM an instanton. Note that any convolution of this $\rho$ with a smoothing function would immediately
create a whole region, instead of just one point, where $\rho$ is not harmonic. Other choices, with $\rho$ harmonic everywhere, would seem to give fields that don't go to zero at large distance.
So I'm still stuck with the "obvious question" mentioned before, and also other aspects of the definition problem:

When is a solution not an instanton?
Shouldn't an extra requirement be that the fields go to $0$ at large $x$ (as the name "instanton" suggests?)
Should it be free of singularities (to avoid calling the Coulomb field in EM an instanton?)

